# Call a Messagebox.Show() from PowerShell with more than default button?

Tags: winforms, powershell

I am trying to show a message box from PowerShell with yes and no buttons.

I can display a message box with an OK button:

```
[system.windows.forms.messagebox]::show("Hello, world!")
```

And I can create a variable $buttons with the buttons I want:

```
$buttons=[system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons].yesno
```

And I can see that the Show() static method is overloaded and that one of the options is to give three parameters:

***Show(String, String, MessageBoxButtons)  Displays a message box with specified text, caption, and buttons.***

So naturally(?) I decided to call this:

```
[system.windows.forms.messagebox]::show("Are you sure?","",$buttons)
```

And this results in an error:

***Cannot find an overload for "Show" and the argument count: "3".***

But there IS an overload for "Show" that accepts three arguments!

What am I doing wrong?

(And can someone tell me why calling a method in PowerShell is usually done by using the dot syntax: object.method() but requires "::" for the MessageBox class? It's confusing.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct way of doing this can be

```
$buttons=[system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons]::yesno;
[system.windows.forms.messagebox]::Show("Are you sure?","",$buttons);
```

Notice "::" instead of "." in the first line. YesNo value is defined staticly on System.Windows.Forms.Messageboxbuttons, so you must use "::" (static call) instead of "."

Note that "[system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons].yesno" is an attempt to call a "YesNo" property on an instance of System.Type, which does not exist and therefore result in a $null

Hope it helps !

Cédric

**Edit ---**

Keith solution using an implicit cast made by powershell for the enum is more elegant.
It just does not work on PS V2 CTP 3 which I still use but work fine on RTM version.
The complete explication was worth giving, though...

Comment: I figured :: was for a static call but then couldn't explain to myself why PowerShell would make that difference. It is clear that MessageBox is a class, not an object; hence :: instead of . seems unecessary. Why add more precise syntax if the interpreter doesn't need it AND it confuses the user?

Comment: Depending on the syntax used (ie :: or .), [YourType] is the equivalent of C# typeof(YourType) or a path to access static methods. The interpreter needs it to know what you want to do ! How would you do ?

Comment: I think I would do it like in C#.

Answer (score 6):

Try this way:

```
[windows.forms.messagebox]::show('body','title','YesNo')
```

And the distinction between using `::` and `.` is static method vs instance method.  Notice above that we didn't create a MessageBox object.  We are just using a static method on MessageBox with the `::` syntax.

Comment: Ok for :: vs ., but your solution does not work (same message as the OP)... maybe an overload resolution problem... should be ok with an explicit cast

Comment: I have verified that it works on both PowerShell 1.0 and 2.0.  Are you sure you're pulling in the Windows Forms assembly: Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms?

Comment: the assembly was added. I'm still using a CTP here. Oh, and the message is 'Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "Show" and the argument count: "3"'.

Comment: I wonder if this was an issue fixed between CTP and the final release??